# How do I connect to a Bluetooth LE device from a DLL

Tags: windows, bluetooth

How do I connect to a Bluetooth LE device from a DLL
I am using VS2015 to build a dll in a .net Framework project on a Windows 10 machine
I will eventually call the dll from LabVIEW 
I can discover BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices by creating a deviceWatcher
From the DeviceWatcher I select a Device which gives me a DeviceInfo.Id like "BluetoothLE#BluetoothLE9c:b6:d0:ca:1f:14-80:1f:12:b5:d8:dc"
When I try to connect using:
BluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceInfo.Id)
I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException, HResult=0x8000000E, A method was called at an unexpected time. Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created

When I try to connect using:

```
Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunTaskAsync(async () =>
{ BluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceInfo.Id); });
```

I get the same error.

It looks as if I need to have a “main window”, which the dll does not.
How do I create a main window for the FromIdAsync to run in?

Useful links I have found, 
BluetoothLEExplorer  https://github.com/Microsoft/BluetoothLEExplorer UWP App that demonstrates BLE connectivity
BLEConsole https://sensboston.github.io/BLEConsole/ Console App with scripting
Both the above use BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync to create the connection

Comment: I can recomend to try Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). Take a look on its console demo. It gives the idea how to use it from DLL.